# how to access a data frame within a spatial data frame object?

Tags: r, spatial-data-frame

I have a  `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object in R called `bikeracks.load` which has within it a
dataframe called `bikeracks.load$Borough`

The original dataset however has an issue with naming one of the borough's.

For instance when i do `unique(bikeracks.load$Borough)`you can see that

```
"Brooklyn"      "Bronx"         "Manhattan"     "manhattan"     "Queens"        "Staten Island"
```

Manhattan is spelt differently in some of the rows. how can I access this dataframe within the sp dataframe object and correct this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

As Ronak says, can you give us sample data? If your spatial data is not *too* different from a normal dataframe, then the base R method would be:

```
bikeracks.load[bikeracks.load$Borough=="manhattan",]$Borough <- "Manhattan"
```

Tested with IRIS data:

```
iris4<-data.frame(iris, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
iris4$Species<-as.character(iris4$Species) #get rid of pesky factor from default iris.
unique(iris4$Species)
iris4[iris4$Species=="virginica",]$Species<-"test"
unique(iris4$Species)
```